# perl find odd odd number in argument

Tags: perl

Example:

```
./odd.pl a a b b b
```

output:

```
b b b
```

find a odd number argument and print

I tried:

```
my %count;
foreach $arg (@ARGV) {
    $count{$arg}++;
    if ($count{$arg} % 2 eq 1) { print "$arg"; }
}

print "\n";
```

Comment: You should add a lot more detail to this question. Are you looking for Perl code to find odd numbers in the argument list?

Comment: my %count;
foreach $arg (@ARGV){

 $count{$arg}++;
 if ($count{$arg} % 2 eq 1){
  print "$arg";
 }
 
}
print "\n"; But not working

Comment: What have you tried? And what makes a even and b odd? They're both letters, not numbers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to print the values that appear an odd number of times.

The problem with your attempt is that you check the counts before you finish obtaining the count of the different values!

Solution:

```
my %counts;
for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    ++$counts{$arg};
}

my @matches;
for my $arg (@ARGV) {
    if ($counts{$arg} % 2 == 1) {
        push @matches, $arg;
    }
}

print("@matches\n");
```

Note that I changed `eq` to `==` because `eq` is for string comparisons.

Simplified solution:

```
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @ARGV;
my @matches = grep { $counts{$_} % 2 } @ARGV;
print("@matches\n");
```

Comment: And wahts the difference between ++$counts{$arg}; And  $counts{$arg}++?

Comment: They don't return quite the same thing. But if you ignore the value they return, there is no difference because `$counts{$arg}++;` gets optimized into `++$counts{$arg};`.